# Strange behavior while adding test case in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

I am facing a strange issue while writing test cases in idea intellij Idea 2016.3.2. We have module, which has some test cases, due to some dependency issue, I have recreated the module and placed the code again.

Now while running test cases the existing test cases are running fine but when I try to add some new test case to existing file, the newly added testcases is not executing, and not even visible in run window which have all the test case names. Additionally when I try to add new test and try to run I got the error as :    **Class not found:"com.xxx.TestCLI"Empty test suite.**

Could anyone help me out in this issue ?

Comment: Have you checked the `Use classpath of module` combobox in the Run Configuration of the test you are trying to run?

Comment: Yes, I have checked,,it is pointing to the same module where I need to run the test.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your IntelliJ configuration is messed, and IntelliJ not able to build/copy the test classes in the appropriate target folder.
1) Close the Project. 
2) Open a cmd console and remove all IntelliJ related project files (*.iml) and folders (.idea).
3) Reopen the Project again.

Then in the menu, do the following:
Build>Rebuild Project.

Now you should be able to run the test.